# Conditional ivysettings file in Ant

Tags: ant

I am trying to adapt an Ant build.xml script to be able to work in both our local office network and within AWS. As such, I have to use a different ivysettings.xml file depending on where the build is happening. In both cases the build is kicked off in Jenkins. My idea was to inject a property 'aws=true' when kicked off from AWS and have the property absent otherwise. We are using Ant 1.7.1 local and a newer version in AWS but I'm not able to see which one right now, build.xml should be able to run on both so 1.7.1 is the limit. I could get this upgraded if necessary.

Can someone help me with the syntax required to adapt this piece of the build.xml file for this purpose?

```
<!-- Resolve dependencies -->
<target name="resolve" description="retrieve dependencies with ivy">
    <ivy:settings file="ivysettings.xml"/>
    <ivy:retrieve sync="true"/>
</target>
```

If aws=true I want to use a file called ivysettings_aws.xml, else ivysettings.xml.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out using ant_contrib.

```
<!-- Resolve dependencies -->
<target name="resolve" description="retrieve dependencies with ivy">
    <if>
        <equals arg1="${aws}" arg2="true" />
        <then>
            <ivy:settings file="ivysettings_aws.xml"/>
        </then>
        <else>
            <ivy:settings file="ivysettings.xml"/>
        </else>
    </if>
    <ivy:retrieve sync="true"/>
</target>
```

Works.

Answer (score 0):

Would the following be simpler?

```
<property name="ivy.settings" value="ivysettings.xml"/>

<target name="resolve" description="retrieve dependencies with ivy">
    <ivy:settings file="${ivy.settings}"/>
    ..
</target>
```

Alternate settings files are then specified as follows:

```
ant -Divy.settings=ivysettings_aws.xml ..
```

Comment: Nice one, thanks! It is simpler. Will the cmd line override the declaration?

Comment: @eric-g  Yes, properties set on the command-line will override the default value within the ANT file.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [new if/unless feature introduced with Ant 1.9.1](http://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html) to get rid of an additional dependency to antcontrib, which is out of service btw., [latest release](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ant-contrib/files/ant-contrib/1.0b3/) 1.0b3 nearly 10 years ago.
Something like :

```
<project 
  xmlns:if="ant:if"
  xmlns:unless="ant:unless"
>

<!-- Resolve dependencies -->
<target name="resolve" description="retrieve dependencies with ivy">
 <ivy:settings file="ivysettings_aws.xml" if:true="${aws}"/>
 <ivy:settings file="ivysettings.xml" unless:true="${aws}"/>
 <ivy:retrieve sync="true" />
</target>

</project>
```

Alternatively use the solution proposed by Mark O' Connor, but you need to remember changing the `-Divy.settings=...` parameter to meet your needs.